# static constexpr member function not callable inside non-template class C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

Consider this non-templated class

```
struct Foo {
    constexpr static bool TRUE() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Calling `Foo::TRUE()` from outside works fine:

```
int main() {
    static_assert(Foo::TRUE(), "");
}
```

but not when called from `Foo` itself:

```
struct Foo {
    constexpr static bool TRUE() {
        return true;
    }
    static_assert(Foo::TRUE(), ""); //ERROR
};
```

> Error (active)    E0028   expression must have a constant value
>   Error   C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant

Even weirder is that this can be "fixed" by providing the class a template:

```
template<int x>
struct Foo {
    constexpr static bool TRUE() {
        return true;
    }
    static_assert(Foo::TRUE(), ""); //compiles fine
};

int main() {
}
```

Even though `Foo::TRUE()` has nothing to do with `int x`.

---

What's going on?

---

*I am using Visual Studio 17 Community Version 15.9.0 - thanks for any help*

Comment: Gcc gives [a somewhat better error message](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c98acd61d66ec6d).

Comment: @nwp so how can you make it fully visible?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it visible"? As far as I can tell the problem is that there is a circular definition. The `static_assert` depends on if `Foo::TRUE()` is `true` which depends on the `static_assert`.

Comment: What if you put the static_assert in the constructor of the struct?

Comment: I expect this to be a 2 pass compilation issue. The compiler runs through the entire class body once before it compiles the body of member functions/static functions. So at the time static_assert is reached, the function TRUE is still considered to not be fully defined which is why it returns an error

Comment: @jwimberley that works, thanks.

Though I am still confused about how the template avoids the circulation.

Comment: [CWG 1626](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1626)