# How does providing a class a template solve invalid constexpr dependencies? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, c++17, constexpr

classes seem to have a problem caling their constexpr member functions in another constexpr context. For example in this piece of code that I proposed [in an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633322/static-constexpr-member-function-not-callable-inside-non-template-class-c) this behaviour can be seen:

```
struct Foo {
    constexpr static bool TRUE() {
        return true;
    }
    static_assert(Foo::TRUE(), ""); //ERROR
};
```

As the `static_assert` depends on `Foo::TRUE()` compilation fails because `Foo::TRUE()` isn't fully resolved in this context yet.

---

So how does adding a single template to `Foo` solve the whole issue?:

```
template<int x>
struct Foo {
    constexpr static bool TRUE() {
        return true;
    }
    static_assert(Foo::TRUE(), ""); //compiles fine
};
```

After all these insights this code here shouldn't compile - yet it does. It doesn't seem to make sense, as there isn't any difference to the non-template version.

Also there should always be equally many `TRUE()`-functions and `static_assert`-calls as there are `Foo<>` classes, so the same dependency problem should occur when compiling.

---

*I am using Visual Studio 17 Community Version 15.9.0 - thanks for any help!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [CWG 1626](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1626):

> The Standard should make clear that a `constexpr` member function cannot be used in a constant expression until its class is complete. For example:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> struct C {
>   template<typename T2> static constexpr bool _S_chk() {
>     return false;
>   }
>   static const bool __value = _S_chk<int>();
> }; 
>
> C<double> c;
> ```
>
> Current implementations accept this, although they reject the corresponding non-template case:
>
> ```
> struct C {
>   static constexpr bool _S_chk() { return false; }
>   static const bool __value = _S_chk();
> };
>
> C c;
> ```
>
> Presumably the template case should be handled consistently with the non-template case.

Comment: so according to the standard the templated `Foo` shouldn't work either, yet the implementation allow it? I see

Comment: What?? This proposal is from 2013, quite old comparing to the current standard. Especially with `if constexpr` in C++17, this restriction will cause a lot of pain to metaprogramming. I mean, the simplest way to compute a type with static branching is to write a function with `auto` return then branching in the function body. If this proposal finally integrated into the standard, such static function must be moved to outside the template...

Comment: @liliscent It's not a proposal, it's an open core language issue.

Comment: @Barry Yeah, I meant this issue. Just there is a suggestion in the issue to forbid this kind of use in template. It will cause much inconvenience.

Comment: @liliscent: It actually won't change much. `if constexpr` means that you're inside of a function. And function definitions are considered to appear just after the class is complete, so you ought to be able to call `constexpr` members just fine.

Comment: @Nicol For example, you can no longer interleave static function with `using` alias to store the type result, nor can you add nontrivial `static_assert` check in a natural location, which will at least make the code less readable. What is weird is that member function in template is instantiated on-demand, it’s a different story with the non-template case, this core issue doesn’t make sense to me.