# Why does static_assert constexpr function not work in non-template struct but works free or in template?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

From the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr int f() { return 42; }
    static_assert(f() == 42); // ERROR
};
```

I'm getting:

> C2131: Expression did not evaluate to a constant

But the following works:

```
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr int f() { return 42; }
};

static_assert(Foo::f() == 42); // OK
```

and the following also works:

```
template<int x>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr int f() { return 42; }
    static_assert(f() == 42); // OK
};
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I once asked the exact same question here: [static constexpr member function not callable inside non-template class C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633322/static-constexpr-member-function-not-callable-inside-non-template-class-c).

Comment: G++'s error is slightly more informative: "<source>:4:20: error: `static constexpr int Foo::f()` called in a constant expression before its definition is complete"