# Why does static_assert on a 'reference to const int' fail?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm now learning how to use `static_assert`. What I learned so far is that the argument of the `static_assert` has to be constant expression. For the following code, I don't know why the argument `reference` is not a constant expression: It is declared as `const` and initialized by integral constant `0`:

```
int main()
{
    const int &reference = 0;
    static_assert(reference);
}
```

The error message from gcc states that the `reference` is not usable in a constant expression:

```
error: 'reference' is not usable in a constant expression.
```

Is there a standard rule that prohibits `reference` from being usable in constant expressions so that it is not a constant expression?

Comment: _"What I learned so far is that the argument of the static_assert has to be constant expression."_ and has to be an rvalue, otherwise, an lvalue-to-rvalue is applied to its argument which is not allowed in constant expression contexts unless some conditions are met.

Comment: You would need something like [that](https://godbolt.org/z/KcxcnjY7T).

Comment: **bound** being the key word here. It's not initialized with 0, it can't be. References have to be bound to objects, so where is that object? `0` does not denote an object, it's just a value.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - Is this mean that there's no temporary created? I think no because `reference` is bound to a const-qualified temporary holding value `0` Right?

Comment: @John - There is a temporary, of course. The reference can't be bound to anything otherwise. The temporary is what trips the points you already mentioned in your other comments. I'm not sure about the temporary being "const qualified", necessarily. Temporaries in general are mutable by default (but that's beside the point here).

Comment: Now what you left to check if the variable is usable in constant expression

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - Is [expr.const#4.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#4.7) satisfied here?

Comment: @John See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#def:usable_in_constant_expressions (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#4.1)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - If you mean that the `reference` needs to be constexpr, the static_assert will be still an error.

Comment: Dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781905/why-does-static-assert-constexpr-function-not-work-in-non-template-struct-but-wo) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72023209/how-to-get-std-array-size-in-a-constant-expression/72023705#72023705).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - Thanks for your reply. Tell me if possible why `reference` is not usable in constant expression. After reading [const.expr](5.8) I realized that (5.8.1) has to be satisfied: But it requires that the non-volatile glvalue `reference` to refer to an object usable in constant expression, but `reference` refer to a const-qualified temporary object, so, Is this temporary usable in constant expressions?

Comment: Dupe/Related: [Why are only some consts useable in compile time array sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72597798/why-are-only-some-consts-useable-in-compile-time-array-sizes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, because you use `static_assert(reference);` instead of `static_assert(!reference);` the program is ill-formed whether or not the operand of `static_assert` is a constant expression, as the assertion will fail. The standard only requires *some* diagnostic for an ill-formed program. It doesn't need to describe the cause correctly. So for the following I will assume you meant `static_assert(!reference);`.

The initialization of `reference` is not a constant expression because the glvalue to which it would be initialized refers to an object which does not have static storage duration (it is a temporary bound to a reference with automatic storage duration), in violation of [[expr.const]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#11). (At least it seems to be the intention that a temporary lifetime-extended through a reference has the storage duration of the reference. This is not clearly specified though, see e.g. https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4840 and linked CWG issues.)

Therefore the reference is not *constant-initialized* (by [[expr.cons]/2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#2.2)) and it is also not `constexpr`, so that the reference is not *usable in constant expressions* (by [[expr.const]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#4)), which is however required of a reference which is referred to by an id-expression in a constant expression if its lifetime didn't start during the constant expression's evaluation (by [[expr.const]/5.12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.12)). Declaring the reference `constexpr` only shifts the issue to the declaration failing for the same reason as above.

If you move the declaration of `reference` to namespace scope it will work (at least after resolution of [CWG 2126](https://wg21.link/cwg2126) and [CWG 2481](https://wg21.link/cwg2481)).

Comment: @foobar No, it refers to the reference.

Comment: After I have read the quotes, (5.8) is checked here: then (5.8.1) is tried: the non-volatile glvalue `reference` refers to an object (in this case the temporary object) that's usable in constant expression: the temporary is usable in constant expressions because it's const-qualified and constant-initialized. So why this exception (5.8.1) is not satisfied here?

Comment: @foobar 5.8 doesn't matter. 5.12. applies because `reference` is a reference.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `(5.8)` is tried before `(5.12)` and because lvalue-to-rvalue is evaluated on the static_assert's argument `reference`

Comment: This less permissive behavior for reference variables is going to be changed for C++23 by the way, but I would need to have a look at the changes again to see whether it will make this well-formed.

Comment: @foobar The whole enumeration begins with "_An expression E is a core constant expression unless [...] one of the following:_". The order doesn't matter. If one of the items applies it is not a core constant expression.

Comment: _"but I would need to have a look at the changes again to see whether it will make this well-formed."_ Thanks alot for this. Belive me I spend more time to understand this point. And I think that you will see that (5.8) has to be checked because after all an lvalue-to-rvalue is involved so the exceptions (5.8.1) and (5.8.2) are tried.

Comment: @foobar I was referring to the C++23 changes which I am not discussing in the answer. Yes, 5.8. must also be checked, but if a later item already applies, then it is redundant to check the prior ones. If any one of the items applies to the expression, then it is not a core constant expression.

Comment: Indeed (5.8.2) is irrelevant - but (5.8.1) is not because I suspect that the glvalue `reference` refer to a (temporary) object _and_ this temporary is usable in constant expression - so I see that this exception has to match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248195/discussion-between-foobar-and-user17732522).